# Which tool can I use to trace the each function's efficiency in a C++ program?

Tags: c++

I am now developing a relatively large C++ program, which is composed of several functions. The C++ program will run these functions sequentially.  What I want to know is how much time and how much memory each function would occupy. For the time consumption one solution is use the [BOOST::Timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/timer/timer.htm) library. For the memory usage, however, I cannot find right library to do the job. I was wondering whether you have some ideas on this question. Moreover, does someone know some tools that can create a program efficiency report similar to [MATLAB profile](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/profile.html)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify your OS or compiler. What you want is generally known as a *profiler*. Using timer for profiling is not a good idea. For memory profiling look for "heap-profiler".

If available for your platform, I'd recomend valgrind's *massif* heap-profiler and optionally *massif-visualizer*.

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

http://gitorious.org/massif-visualizer